# MySQL cannot select a row inserted in a different session

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb, powerbuilder

My question is in the title.

I open a MySQL session in an application, and that application calls a script that creates another session.  I insert a record in that new session, but when I select in the previous session, I cannot see the inserted row.

The following is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO VCS.project_files (track_nbr, path, filename)
     VALUES ('$track_nbr', '$path', '$filename');
```

The following is the select:

```
SELECT pf.project_file_id, pf.track_nbr, pf.filename, pf.path, pf.status
    FROM VCS.project_files pf;
```

Comment: Are you using transactions?  Replication?  Can we see the SQL queries?

Comment: Hi Jesse, I updated my post with the queries.

Comment: Thanks for trying Jesse, I somehow managed to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out this was due to isolation level set to 'repeatable reads'.  'Repeatable reads' means exactly what it says, each read in the old session will get the **exact same rows**.

In order to fix this, I had to set the database to 'read committed' by doing the following:

1. Adding the following lines to `/etc/my.cnf` (Ubuntu) `/etc/my.cnf.d/my.cnf` (CentOS):

   ```
   [mysqld]
   binlog_format = row
   transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
   ```
2. Restarting MySQL (in Ubuntu):

   ```
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

This allows all sessions to see **committed** changes from other sessions.

I was used to Oracle database ('read committed' by default) and MySQL is different ('repeatable reads' by default).

Comment: You also need to do a `COMMIT` sometime, else it will timeout after a default of 50 seconds and automatically rollback whatever you are doing.